# SQL Server : complicated query

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables `document` and `documentd`; the first one contains the numbers of the invoices `doc_num` as primary key, document types `doc_type` (FACA, BLCO, BLCM, BLCK .....) and the document date `doc_date`.

Each invoice has one `DOC_TYPE` and one date, and each date my be contained in one or more invoices.

Table `DOCUMENT`:

| DOC_NUM | DOC_TYPE | DOC_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| INVOICE1901221 | FACA | 22/01/2019 |
| INVOICE1902221 | FACA | 22/02/2019 |
| INVOICE1902222 | FACA | 22/02/2019 |
| INVOICE1903221 | FACA | 22/03/2019 |
| BLCO190122001 | BLCO | 22/01/2019 |
| BLCO190123001 | BLCO | 23/01/2019 |
| BLCM190122001 | BLCM | 22/01/2019 |
| INVOICE1901021 | FACA | 02/01/2019 |
| INVOICE1903011 | FACA | 01/03/2019 |
| INVOICE1904221 | FACA | 22/04/2019 |
| INVOICE1904222 | FACA | 22/04/2019 |

The second table is the details of each invoices he contains as foreign key `doc_num` the code of products for each invoice `art_code` and finally the prices of the products `art_price`.

Table `DOCUMENTD`:

| DOC_NUM | ART_CODE | ART_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| INVOICE1901221 | PRODUCT1 | 1000 |
| INVOICE1901221 | PRODUCT2 | 2000 |
| INVOICE1902221 | PRODUCT3 | 950 |
| INVOICE1902221 | PRODUCT4 | 980 |
| INVOICE1904221 | PRODUCT1 | 1200 |
| INVOICE1903011 | PRODUCT2 | 900 |
| BLCO190122001 | ARTICLE1 | 900 |
| BLCO190123001 | ARTICLE2 | 800 |

[DOCUMENTD TABLE][2]

My goal in first step is to join the two tables using `doc_num` selects all `FACA` type invoices and their products except the prices they must be THE LAST UPDATED PRICE IN FACA TYPE.

**RESULT:**

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INVOICE1904221 | PRODUCT1 | 1200 | 22/04/2019 |
| INVOICE1903011 | PRODUCT2 | 900 | 01/03/2019 |
| INVOICE1902221 | PRODUCT3 | 950 | 22/02/2019 |
| INVOICE1902221 | PRODUCT4 | 980 | 22/02/2019 |

The second step I have another table how contain `ORDER` and `ART_CODE`:

| ORDER | ART_CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PRODUCT1 |
| 2 | PRODUCT2 |
| 3 | PRODUCT3 |

I want to fetch the first result depend on this table:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INVOICE1904221 | PRODUCT1 | 1200 | 22/04/2019 |
| INVOICE1903011 | PRODUCT2 | 900 | 01/03/2019 |
| INVOICE1902221 | PRODUCT3 | 950 | 22/02/2019 |

I try this but he fetch same product with different prices

```sql
SELECT 
    d1.DOC_NUM, dd1.ART_CODE, dd2.ART_PRICE, d2.DOC_DATE 
FROM
    document d1 
INNER JOIN 
    documentd dd1 ON dd1.DOC_NUM = d1.DOC_NUM
INNER JOIN 
    documentd dd2 ON dd2.ART_CODE = dd1.ART_CODE
INNER JOIN 
    document d2 ON d2.DOC_NUM = dd2.DOC_NUM 
                AND d2.DOC_TYPE <> d1.DOC_TYPE
WHERE 
    d1.DOC_TYPE = 'FACA'
```

Comment: I do not understand `...except the prices they must be THE LAST UPDATED PRICE IN FACA TYPE`. What do you mean by that? Furthermore I do not understand the sense of that one: `The second step I have another table how contain ORDER and ART_CODE`, what means that? What is this table for? You are not joining it.

Comment: I want to select from the **DOCUMENTD** table the  products with the last price depend on the newest date from **DOCUMENT** table and with **DOC_TYPE** FACA and show only the products who existed in the last table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MOHAMED NEJI it's really hard to understand what you meant. Please try to be more clear on your questions.
The proposed solution below shows how to get the results you asked in both RESULTS tables with the input data that you gave.

```
CREATE TABLE #DOCUMENT (
    DOC_NUM VARCHAR(30)
    , DOC_TYPE  CHAR(4)
    , DOC_DATE DATE)
CREATE TABLE #DOCUMENTD (
    DOC_NUM VARCHAR(30)
    , ART_CODE VARCHAR(20)
    , ART_PRICE DECIMAL(10,4))
CREATE TABLE #OTHERTABLE(
    [ORDER] int  
    , ART_CODE VARCHAR(20)
)


INSERT INTO #DOCUMENT
          SELECT 'INVOICE1901221' DOC_NUM, 'FACA' DOC_TYPE, '2019-01-22' DOC_DATE
UNION ALL SELECT 'INVOICE1902221' DOC_NUM, 'FACA' DOC_TYPE, '2019-02-22' DOC_DATE
UNION ALL SELECT 'INVOICE1902222' DOC_NUM, 'FACA' DOC_TYPE, '2019-02-22' DOC_DATE
UNION ALL SELECT 'INVOICE1903221' DOC_NUM, 'FACA' DOC_TYPE, '2019-03-22' DOC_DATE
UNION ALL SELECT 'BLCO190122001'  DOC_NUM, 'BLCO' DOC_TYPE, '2019-01-22' DOC_DATE
UNION ALL SELECT 'BLCO190123001'  DOC_NUM, 'BLCO' DOC_TYPE, '2019-01-23' DOC_DATE
UNION ALL SELECT 'BLCM190122001'  DOC_NUM, 'BLCM' DOC_TYPE, '2019-01-22' DOC_DATE
UNION ALL SELECT 'INVOICE1901021' DOC_NUM, 'FACA' DOC_TYPE, '2019-01-02' DOC_DATE
UNION ALL SELECT 'INVOICE1903011' DOC_NUM, 'FACA' DOC_TYPE, '2019-03-01' DOC_DATE
UNION ALL SELECT 'INVOICE1904221' DOC_NUM, 'FACA' DOC_TYPE, '2019-04-22' DOC_DATE
UNION ALL SELECT 'INVOICE1904222' DOC_NUM, 'FACA' DOC_TYPE, '2019-04-22' DOC_DATE

INSERT INTO #DOCUMENTD
          SELECT 'INVOICE1901221' DOC_NUM, 'PRODUCT1' ART_CODE, 1000  ATR_PRICE
UNION ALL SELECT 'INVOICE1901221' DOC_NUM, 'PRODUCT2' ART_CODE, 2000  ATR_PRICE
UNION ALL SELECT 'INVOICE1902221' DOC_NUM, 'PRODUCT3' ART_CODE, 950   ATR_PRICE
UNION ALL SELECT 'INVOICE1902221' DOC_NUM, 'PRODUCT4' ART_CODE, 980   ATR_PRICE
UNION ALL SELECT 'INVOICE1904221' DOC_NUM, 'PRODUCT1' ART_CODE, 1200  ATR_PRICE
UNION ALL SELECT 'INVOICE1903011' DOC_NUM, 'PRODUCT2' ART_CODE, 900   ATR_PRICE
UNION ALL SELECT 'BLCO190122001'  DOC_NUM, 'ARTICLE1' ART_CODE, 900   ATR_PRICE
UNION ALL SELECT 'BLCO190123001'  DOC_NUM, 'ARTICLE2' ART_CODE, 800   ATR_PRICE

INSERT INTO #OTHERTABLE
          SELECT 1 [ORDER], 'PRODUCT1' ART_CODE
UNION ALL SELECT 2 [ORDER], 'PRODUCT2' ART_CODE
UNION ALL SELECT 3 [ORDER], 'PRODUCT3' ART_CODE

;WITH Docs AS (
    SELECT  dd.DOC_NUM, dd.ART_CODE, dd.ART_PRICE, d.DOC_DATE ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  art_code ORDER BY DOC_DATE DESC ) rn
    FROM #DOCUMENTD  dd
    INNER JOIN #DOCUMENT d 
        ON d.DOC_NUM = dd.DOC_NUM
    WHERE DOC_TYPE =  'FACA'
)
SELECT  DOC_NUM, ART_CODE, ART_PRICE, DOC_DATE 
FROM Docs
WHERE rn = 1

;WITH Docs AS (
    SELECT  dd.DOC_NUM, dd.ART_CODE, dd.ART_PRICE, d.DOC_DATE ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  art_code ORDER BY DOC_DATE DESC ) rn
    FROM #DOCUMENTD  dd
    INNER JOIN #DOCUMENT d 
        ON d.DOC_NUM = dd.DOC_NUM
    WHERE DOC_TYPE =  'FACA'
)
SELECT  DOC_NUM, Docs.ART_CODE, ART_PRICE, DOC_DATE 
FROM Docs
INNER JOIN #OTHERTABLE ot
   ON ot.ART_CODE = Docs.ART_CODE
WHERE rn = 1
```